# Having problems linking table at a specific webpage in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to pull live data from http://www.wdol.gov/sca.aspx into an Excel spreadsheet.  Specifically the SCA Wage Determined Rates.  I want to be able to pull in the table that is generated from the State/County into my workbook; however, I am having trouble even linking the website.

I seem to be able to link everything on the website into my workbook except for the table that the website generates.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The table you're trying to link to is generated by javascript. You cannot link to it in Excel, as it's not associated with a static URL. One alternative might be to automate an instance of Internet Explorer to choose the relevant form options then pull the resulting table data. Here's a start for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409613/vba-to-enter-data-online-and-submit-form